# input text field focus on keydown

Tags: jquery, input, focus, field, keydown

I have a couple of input text fields which are all separate, but I want that when you start typing 1 gets focused.

I think I have to do this with jquery `.bind()` but I'm not sure:

```
$(document).bind('keydown',function(e){
    $('#defaultInput').focus();
    $(document).unbind('keydown');
});
```

And you can keep doing that. The code I have now lets me do this action only once and doesn't check if I'm typing in another box.

Is there a way with jquery to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

If you have for example these 3 input fields on your page:

```
<input type="text" id="t1" />
<input type="text" id="t2" />
<input type="text" id="t3" />
```

With the following JS, it will only focus the second one, if the focus isn't on t1 or t3 or any other input element on the page.

```
$(document).bind('keydown',function(e){
    if ($(':focus:not("input")').length){
        $('#t2').focus();
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/gPs45/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).one('onkeydown',function(e){
  $(':input:first').focus();
});
```

Use the jQuery [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to only bind once on the page (this makes it more convenient than binding/unbinding). Then it's up to you if you want to catch `keyChar` and push that in to the field with it so they don't "lose" that first keystroke.